# Column data types classification in R

Tags: r

I have a database. How to get all of colums types, and save it to a file. Distinctive types:
- Float
- Integer
- BigInteger
- String

My code is:

```
   library(foreign)
   library(memisc)
   data <- read.spss("data.sav", use.value.labels = FALSE, max.value.labels = 100)
   write.table(summary(data), "out.txt")
```

But, this code only distinguishes between two types of data... (numeric, String)

out sample:

```
                            Length Class  Mode     
SubsID                      20582  -none- numeric  
SubsID_RN                   20582  -none- character
responseid                  20582  -none- numeric
```

required output:

```
SubsID                      BigInteger
SubsID_RN                   String
responseid                  Integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, the type system works differently from many of the other common languages. First of, everything in R is an object and one of the basic object types is the `vector`. The type of the vector itself is defined by the data that it contains. There are six atomic vector types which can be accessed by the `typeof` function. In the R documentation you can find the following table

```
+------------+----------+--------------+
|   typeof   |   mode   | storage.mode |
+------------+----------+--------------+
| logical    | logical  | logical      |
| integer    | numeric  | integer      |
| double     | numeric  | double       |
| complex    | complex  | complex      |
| character  | character| character    |
| raw        | raw      | raw          |
+------------+----------+--------------+
```

As you can see, there is no difference between float and double or Integer and BigInteger. Also a String is just a character in R.

So in your case, if you want to know the specific basic type of each of your variables, you could use

```
lapply(data, typeof)
```

The R documentation has more information about objects and basic types:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Objects

Answer (score 1):

you can call the class or the type of your columns like this:

```
lapply(your_data_frame, class)
lapply(your_data_frame, typeof)
```

there's no such thing as 'BigInteger' in R. cf. [data structures in hadley's adv-r](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) for a more detailed explanation